# Which is correct: "via/on/in/with a messenger"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is correct: "via/on/in/with a messenger"? If more than one is correct, are there any shades of using different prepositions with "messenger"?

Comment: If *messenger* is here intended to refer to a software application, as one of the comments to the answer implies, that needs to be made explicit within the question—that is not the primary sense of the word.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what you wish to say. Without a specific example I will interpolate.

*He told me this via a messenger.* would explain how his news got to you.
The news received would be *in a message* not in a messenger.
You would be told the news *with a message*. Or something in addition to the message *came with a messenger*.
I would say shades of meaning would be more useful to the word message than messenger.

Comment: I see, thanks. What about an example like this - "I talk to my friends  via/on/in a messenger", meaning we are using a messenger to talk/ chat.

Comment: It would be much the same. You communicate via/through a messenger. Give them news in/via a message.